# Sharing WiFi Internet connection via Ethernet from Win 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm currently setting up my first ever Ubuntu machine, and ran into some trouble sharing the Internet from my Win 7 computer.

The Windows 7 computer is connected to the Internet via WiFi, and is connected to the Ubuntu machine via Ethernet cable. My goal is for the Ubuntu machine to be able to access the Internet via the Win 7 machine.

I found some tutorials for sharing the other way around, but can't seem to get it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to network adapter settings on the Win 7 machine
2. Click on the wireless network adapter
3. Hold CTRL and click the ethernet adapter
4. Click the option to bridge the connections
5. For good measure, change the IPV4 settings for the ethernet adapter to use an unused IP on your network with the same subnet and your router's IP address as the gateway

That should allow the Ubuntu machine to act as though it is connected to a router via ethernet. You shouldnt have to do much if anything on the Ubuntu machine.
Sorry for the somewhat vague terminology but I am not currently in front of my computer.